# Static map used before it is initialized

Tags: c++, static, std

I'm trying to implement a factory pattern like [this](https://gist.github.com/sacko87/3359911).

The problem right now is that the program terminates with a segfault in the register function because the map is not initialized yet.

```
// initialise the registered names map
std::map<std::string, factoryMethod> SourceFactory::registeredClasses_ = { };

bool SourceFactory::Register(std::string name, factoryMethod createMethod) {
    // registeredClasses_ = { }; // This prevents the segfault but does not work for obvious reasons
    auto temp = std::make_pair(name.c_str(), createMethod);

    std::pair<std::map<std::string, factoryMethod>::iterator, bool> registeredPair =
            SourceFactory::registeredClasses_.insert(temp);

    return registeredPair.second;
}
```

Why is it possible for `Register()` to be called before the initialization of the map? I tried initializing the map in the header file but then I get the linker error

> multiple definition of SourceFactory::registeredClasses_

A solution would be to set a static bool `isInitialized=false` and then initialize the map accordingly. But I hope this can be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible when `Register` is called from a different translation unit before the registry has been initialised.
Unfortunately, adding a static flag would not solve anything because that would not be initialised either.

A convenient solution is to add a level of indirection:

```
// static
std::map<std::string, factoryMethod>& SourceFactory::registry()
{
    static std::map<std::string, factoryMethod> registeredClasses;
    return registeredClasses;
}

bool SourceFactory::Register(const std::string& name, factoryMethod createMethod) {
    auto temp = std::make_pair(name, createMethod);
    return registry().insert(temp).second;
}
```

Comment: This isn't really indirection in the common sense but it certainly is the solution. The key is _when_ objects of static storage duration are constructed, which depends on the _where_ of their declaration.

Comment: Do note that there are potential problems with having this `registeredClasses` be a map rather than a pointer to a dynamically allocated one (see the ref linked-to from my answer), although personally I prefer it the way you've done it, not only because it's cleaner, but because I find the dynamically-allocated approach to be a totally hackish way to solve what should really be a non-problem in many cases

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem known as the [*static initialisation order fiasco*](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).

Objects with static storage duration at namespace scope are constructed in-order within a translation unit, but you don't know whether those in other translation units may undergo initialisation first.

Instead of having your container at namespace scope, make it *function static* (perhaps returned from a new `GetRegistry()` function?) so that it is constructed on first use. That could be use from `main`, use from initialisation of another static-duration "thing" (which is presumably where your `Register` call is coming from), use from the moon…

This is also why the proper way to write a singleton is to have a `GetInstance()` function that declares (`static`ly!) the instance *within* the function's scope.

> A solution would be to set a static bool isInitialized=false and then initialize the map accordingly. But I hope this can be avoided.

Nope. Not only would you then have the same problem with the `isInitialized` flag, but there's nothing you can "do" with that information. You can't "initialize" something other than in an initializer, and the whole problem is that the initializer hasn't been used yet. You could assign to the map, but that would have undefined behaviour because you'd be assigning to something that doesn't exist yet… and then it would be initialized later anyway!